# Execute bash after terminating webpack-dev-server

Tags: linux, node.js, bash, webpack-dev-server

Here's a small annoyance. As part of a project's "quickstart" script I'm starting a webpack server in a terminal tab, along other things in other tabs, in short:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

gnome-terminal --tab --tab --command \
    'bash -c "node_modules/.bin/webpack-dev-server; exec bash"' &
```

This almost works as supposed to -- with the exception of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> in the server's tab. If it were, say, a Flask server, it would get stopped and a bash prompt would appear in the same tab (that's the reason for the "exec bash" part). But with node / webpack the tab just closes.

Manually sending an interrupt signal to the node process leaves the tab open (e.g. `kill -INT <pid>`). So the question is what is happening from the operating system perspective. What process tree is created? Which process gets the *SIGINT*? What gets replaced by exec (if anything)?

Possibly related: https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/4432.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to use `trap` as follow:

```
bash -c "trap 'exec bash' SIGINT; node_modules/.bin/webpack-dev-server;"
```

it must kill webpack-dev-server and exec bash on cmd+c;

Comment: Thanks, trapping indeed works. Here's some basic info if anyone was interested: [Traps@TLDP](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_12_02.html). Still, it would be nice to understand why is it needed in this case.